# Trying to erase the line drawn on one click in inkcanvas

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to erase the line drawn  on one click in inkcanvas.
My requirement is that, if I draw a line or whatever pattern on the given area,
it will erase all line drawn in one click and again if I draw anything and click 'erase' button it will clear all lines drawn on current screen.

Xaml

```xml
<Grid x:Name="Bg_BigRect" Background="White"
       Width="310" Height="440"
       RelativePanel.Below="Bg_Rect"
       Margin="24,10,0,0">
    <Image x:Name="Trans_Tex" Source="WorkBook/T0.png"                              
           Margin="-10,0,0,20" 
           Width="310" Height="370"/>
        <InkCanvas x:Name="ink"/>
</Grid>
```

C# code

```cs
public WorkBook()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ink.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;     

    // Set initial ink stroke attributes.
    InkDrawingAttributes drawingAttributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
    drawingAttributes.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
    drawingAttributes.IgnorePressure = false;
    drawingAttributes.FitToCurve = true;
    ink.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(drawingAttributes);
}

private void W_ClearTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ink.InkPresenter.InputProcessingConfiguration.Mode = InkInputProcessingMode.Erasing;
}
```

Refer image

[image: Screenshot of application]

Comment: `ink.InkPresenter.Strokes.Clear()`. btw. that's an odd way to draw an `A`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer i tried but it is giving error "InkPresenter" doesn't contains a definition for "Strokes".Could you show Example how to achieve it.

Comment: That's weird, it should have a [Strokes Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkpresenter.strokes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm using vs2015 and My uwp app target version is build 14393.It is giving error

Answer (score 0):

For UWP apps, you can use [InkStrokeContainer.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStrokeContainer_Clear) method. For example:

```
ink.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.Clear();
```